# Java: sorting an array with lambda expression?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I've recently got into functional programming and Java 8 lambdas. I have an array of ints and I want to sort it in an ascending order.

The way I am trying to do this with lambda is as follows:

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y) == -1);
```

The issue with this is that my compiler says:

```
Error:(12, 32) java: method sorted in interface 
java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: (x,y)->Int[...]== -1
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Streams do not offer a way to sort an array, they allow to *process the elements* in a sorted order. The original array is not modified and in your case, since there is no actual operation, nothing will happens at all. To sort an array, use `Arrays.sort(array);` that’ll work for `int[]` and `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 5):

A `Comparator` takes two `Object` and returns an `int`.

Here, we're entering with two `Object`'s but are returning a boolean expression (`Integer.compare(x, y) == -1`)

You actually just need the first part of it

```
Arrays.stream(intArray)
      .sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y))
      .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

---

Since you seem to be using an array of `Integer` objects (because an `IntStream` doesn't have a `sorted(Comparator)` method) you better be using a simple `IntStream`, it will simplify your life because the `int` will than be sorted in their natural order.

### `IntStream#sorted()`

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream in sorted
>   order.

```
Arrays.stream(intArray)
      .mapToInt(x->x)
      .sorted()
      .toArray();
```

Comment: That was my original approach. But even doing it this way, it still gives me the "Integer.Compare(x, y)" cannot be applied to <lambda expression> , <lambda expression>

Comment: @Kobek May you please post the full code? With the `intArray`, it'll help reproduce the problem.

Comment: Both of these are incomplete; because there is no terminal operation, neither does anything.  You want a `toArray()` at the end (or similar.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz You were totally right. Is it better now?

Comment: Since the result is the sorted array returned by `toArray()` you should assign the result to a variable (in the first case, assigning it to the existing `intArray` would be fine, in the second, the result is `int[]` where the source is `Integer[]`)…

Comment: All these methods are great, but my main problem here is that no matter what I do, every time I call the .sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y)

I get an error, saying that x and y cannot be compared as they are lambda expressions.

For anyone still interested, here is the full code of my program (commented) http://pastebin.com/HXmNUeXx

Comment: @Kobek: this has already been explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36370900/2711488)…

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The error in your case is because [`IntStream#sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) does not take parameters.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/SjGmwL)

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.stream(intArray).sorted()` Should be used for processing the array in a specific order. It can be used to sort arrays as explained in other answers but it will generate a new sorted array.

```
Arrays.stream(intArray)
      .sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y))
      .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

In case of very big sized data this will not be efficient.

If you want to do in-place sorting, you can use Collections.sort()

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (x,y) -> Integer.compare(x,y))
```

Or in the case of objects of type A and sorting based on field P

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(A::getP))
```

where getP() is the method that gets the field P value.

In case of reversed sorting

```
 Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(A::getP).reversed())
```

In case of sorting on 2 fields P and P2

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(A::getP).thenComparing(A::getP2))
```

Comment: How to sort a raw array like `int[] arr` with a lambda that has multiple lines (various if elses). Something like this: `Arrays.sort(arr, <multi-line lambda>);`